# Angular - pdf won't render until resize

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, pdf, angular-ui-router

So I have a pdf that I'm making an ajax call for with angular, which all goes fine. Only chrome won't render the pdf. Unless I resize the window, like by opening console, then it suddenly shows  up. The same code seems fine in FF.

JS:

```js
app.factory('pdfFactory', function ($http) {
return {
    getData: function() {
       return $http.get('api/pdf', {responseType:'arraybuffer'}).then(function (res) {
            var file = new Blob([res.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            return fileURL;
        });
    }
};
});

app.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('pdf', {
        url: '/pdf',
        templateUrl: 'js/pdf/pdf.html',
        resolve: {
            pdf : function(pdfFactory) {
                return pdfFactory.getData();
            }
        },
        controller: 'pdfctrl'
    });
});


app.controller('pdfctrl', function ($scope, pdf, $sce) {
       $scope.pdf = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(pdf);
});
```

html:

```js
<embed ng-src="{{pdf}}" style="height: 100vw; width: 90vw; margin-left: 10vw;"></embed>
```

ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to add ng-if for embed.

```
app.controller('pdfctrl', function ($scope, pdf, $sce) {
       $scope.pdf = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(pdf);
       $scope.pdfContent = true;
});
```

Embed will show after trustAsResourceUrl.

```
<embed ng-if="pdfContent" ng-src="{{pdf}}" style="height: 100vw; width: 90vw; margin-left: 10vw;"></embed>
```

**OR**
Use object instead of embed:

```
<object ng-if="pdfContent" data="{{pdf}}" type="application/pdf" style="height: 100vw; width: 90vw; margin-left: 10vw;"></object>
```

Comment: Using `<object>` along with `ng-if` seemed to do the trick for me. Not sure why Chrome was having beef with `<embed>`.... Thanks!